# What is the format of the Qpdeltamap used for ROI in NVENC?

Tags: h.264, nvidia, video-encoding

I am trying to get started with ROI encoding with the Nvidia Encoder NVENC.
As a first step I am trying to get the Nvidia demos to encode using ROI. I know that the switch -qpDeltaMapFile enables the flag enableExtQPDeltaMap. This allows me to send a file with a qp map that the encoder uses to tweak the values obtained by the rate control algorithm.

However there is absolutely no documentation on the format of this file. I tried to use one value per byte, and one byte per value assuming fixed size macroblocks of 16x16. It doesn't seem to work as I would expect.

Any guidance or references would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in my code. It actually works almost as I described.
Assume your screen is divided equally in 16x16 blocks, then each value will be added to the qp that the rate control algorithm chose. Each value passed is a signed integer, therefore a negative value will improve the quality while a positive value will decrease it. A value of 0 will stay with whatever the rate control algorithm decided.